# Python: Draw a 2d grid and allow coloring of cells

Tags: python

I want to simulate the game of life problem using python. I want to draw a grid and be able to color its cells as the simulation progresses. How do I do that in Python?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [pygame](http://www.pygame.org/) to do that.

To display the state of your simulation, you should create an 8 bit surface with a palette, and access it with the [pygame.surfarray](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surfarray.html) module.

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at [PyGame](http://www.pygame.org) too.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest [Gloss](http://www.tuxradar.com/gloss), it's like PyGame except hardware accelerated. It also provides many other game-programming goodies.

Comment: Just be careful on the licensing implications of Gloss as it's GPLv3 rather than PyGame's LGPL.

Comment: Gloss' README states that version 0.85 (2010-01-23) was relicensed under the LGPL.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest taking a look at the Python Imaging Library (PIL) [documentation](http://www.pythonware.com/library/pil/handbook/index.htm)

Comment: I think that for a game PyGame is a better fit as it also draws to the screen.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old post, but in the name of building the perfect QA site, I would suggest [matplotlib](http://matplotlib.org/).

As of this writing, it looks like matplotlib development is getting more attention than [pygame development](https://bitbucket.org/pygame/pygame/src).